# document ready() not working in firefox giving null for DOM element...ie7 working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I have come across a need to click an element automatically after a page has been loaded, so I implemented the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('handler2').click();
    });
</script>
```

Which is working fine in IE7, but not firefox.  When I run the script in firefox 3 I get the following error: `document.getElementById("handler2") is null`

Which I believe is null, because the page (in firefox) hasn't loaded the DOM entirely where the id "handler2" is located...but I don't get it.  Why would it load the DOM in IE, but not Firefox?  I read some posts that stated firefox in firefox3 made some changes to how javascript is executed, which might cause the problem. Perhaps the "document.ready" is being executed too soon in firefox3?

Anyone got any ideas or how to fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

This isn't the best output, but the full source is too large for stackoverflow to accept.  If you search for "handler2" you should find it inside an  tag. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <HTML><BODY id="srp" style="MARGIN-TOP: 2px; MARGIN-LEFT: 2px; CURSOR: default; COLOR: black; MARGIN-RIGHT: 2px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white"><TABLE id="mainTable" height="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0" valign="top"><TBODY><TR><TD class="contentcell" vAlign="top" width="100%" height="100%"><TABLE class="manager" id="searchManager" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><TBODY><TR><TD class="managerBody" id="managerBody"><TABLE class="searchManager setHeight panelGroup" id="managerTable" style="HEIGHT: 536px" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><TBODY><TR><TD class="panelFrame filters" id="secondaryPod"><DIV class="filters setHeight" id="filters" style="HEIGHT: 503px"><DIV class="wrapper" id="filtersWrapper"><DIV class="content setHeight" id="searchFilters" style="HEIGHT: 503px"><DIV class="foldersPanel setHeight" id="foldersPanel" style="HEIGHT: 503px"><DIV class="content panelBorder foldersTree" oncontextmenu="return false;" id="foldersTree" style="WIDTH: 267px; HEIGHT: 150px"><DIV id="node1sub" style="DISPLAY: block"><DIV id="node2"><NOBR> <IMG id="handler2" style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; WIDTH: 19px; HEIGHT: 20px" src="images/treeimages/plus_last.gif" /> </NOBR></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

---

Here's the Source Code.  This is using 3rd party .jsp on tomcat.  You won't be able to see the expanded list because a java process is creating it, but there is an element "handler2" with a click event that I am triggering.  I hope this isn't too much code to clutter up the question.  My script is at the very bottom.  This .jsp page is using prototype.js, which is why I was using the "no conflict" so I could use jquery...I don't know prototype.js

Source Code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/jasperserver.tld" prefix="js" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/spring" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="authz" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ page errorPage="/WEB-INF/jsp/JSErrorPage.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/customtooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/std_treelook.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/manager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/toolkit/parts/css/infiniteScroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/toolkit/parts/css/optionSet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/toolkit/parts/css/tabularList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/searchMenus.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/search-ie-specific.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/manager/ie-specific.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/manager/ie7-specific.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->

    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/edition.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/dialog.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/checkbox-utils.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/table.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/customTooltip.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/nanotree.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/treesupport.js"></script>

    <%--<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/toolkit/utilities/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/toolkit/parts/javascript/tabularList.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/toolkit/parts/javascript/infiniteScroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/rootObjectModifier.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/components.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/dnd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/resourceactions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/folderactions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/bulkactions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/search/searchLayoutManager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/e.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        webHelpModule.currentContext = "search";

    </script>

</head>

<body id="srp" >

<table id="searchManager" class="manager" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
    <tr><td class="fsection managerTitle"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="managerBody" class="managerBody">
            <table id="managerTable" class="searchManager setHeight panelGroup" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                <tr style="height:1px;">
                    <td style="height:1px;"id="filtersHeader" class="panelHeader mainListFrame">&nbsp;
      <!--COMMENTED BY AARON removes the label "SEARCH"
                        <h2>
        <spring:message code="SEARCH_FILTERS" javaScriptEscape="true"/>
      </h2>
      -->
                    </td>
                    <td style="height:1px;" class="panelHeader sizerFrame" > </td>
                    <td style="height:1px;" class="panelHeader">&nbsp;
      <!--COMMENTED BY AARON removes the label "REPOSITORY"
                        <h2>
        <spring:message code="SEARCH_RESOURCE_TITLE" javaScriptEscape="true"/>
      </h2>
      -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="secondaryPod" class="panelFrame filters">
                        <div id="filters" class="filters setHeight">
                            <div id="filtersWrapper" class="wrapper">
                                <div id="searchFilters" class="content setHeight">
                                    <div id="foldersPanel" class="foldersPanel setHeight">
                                        <!--COMMENTED BY AARON to remove the header class which draws the box around the "include subfolders checkbox" see tag below
           <div class="header">
          -->
          <div class="">
                                            <!-- COMMENTED BY AARON Hides the SEARCH TEXT BOX options for filtering
                                            <div id="js-search-secondary-control" class="js-search-control" style="width: 100%">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input id="secondarySearchText" name="searchText" type="text" class="rndCorners-all default" value=""/>
                                                            <div id="secondaryClearBtn" title="<spring:message code='SEARCH_BOX_CLEAR_LABEL'/>" class="clear setHidden">&nbsp;</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="button">
                                                            <button id="secondarySearchBtn" class="submit up" title="<spring:message code='SEARCH_BOX_SEARCH_LABEL'/>" type="submit">
                                                                <spring:message code='SEARCH_BOX_SEARCH_LABEL'/>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>
           -->


                                        </div>
                                        <div id="foldersTree" class="content panelBorder foldersTree" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
           <!-- Controls the Checkbox for "Include Subfolders"
            by moving the div below to "after the <div id="foldersTree"> it effectively hides the checkbox, other wise
            the whole folder of reports gets hidden if u try to comment it
           -->
                                            <div >
                                                <input id="searchMode" type="checkbox" class="modeSelector setHidden"/>
                                                <span id="searchModeLabel" class="checkboxLabel setHidden">
             <spring:message code='SEARCH_SWICH_MODE'/>
            </span>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="filtersPanel" class="filtersPanel filterList panelBorder" style="display:none;"></div>

         <table id="filtersTable" class="panelBorder" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="panelHeader mainListFrame">
                                                <h2>
             <!--COMMENTED BY AARON .  Removes the "Refine Label"
             <spring:message code="SEARCH_REFINE" javaScriptEscape="true"/>
             -->
            </h2>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!--COMMENTED BY AARON. Removes the first top row for the REFINE category
          <tr>
                                            <td class="panelBorder top">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
          -->
                                        </tbody>
                                        <!---->
          <tbody>
                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="sizerFrame">
      <!--ADDED BY AARON. Added the "Style" portion to add a different box around the resizer
        <div id="vSizer" class="setHeight sizer vertical">
      -->
                        <div id="vSizer" class="setHeight sizer vertical" style="border-width:1px;border:#F0F0F0;border-style:solid;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="primaryPod" class="panelFrameLast result">
                        <div id="result" class="panelBorder setHeight setWidth">
                            <div id="resultWrapper" class="wrapper">
                                <div class="toolbar container labels">
                                    <div class="buttonSet fl">
                                        <input id="bulkCheckbox" class="bulkSelector" value="" type="checkbox">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="bulkBar" class="buttonSet fl">
                                    </div>
                                    <%--<div id="createResourceBar" class="buttonSet fl">--%>
                                        <%--<button id="createResource" class="toolbarBtn complex up">--%>
                                            <%--<span class="label">&nbsp;</span>--%>
                                            <%--<span class="menuSignal">&nbsp;</span>--%>
                                        <%--</button>--%>
                                    <%--</div>--%>
                                    <div class="cb"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="toolbar secondary bulkBar">
                                    <div id="filterPath" class="container" style="float:left;">
                                        <ul class="tabSet optionSet"></ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="searchSort" class="container">
                                        <ul id="sortBar" class="tabSet optionSet"></ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="float:none;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="" class="<%--wrapper--%> tabularList setMyWidth" <%--style="display: none"--%>>

                                    <table id="allResultsHeaderTable" class="setMyWidth" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr class="headers">
                                            <th class="bulkSelector" scope="col"></th>
                                            <th class="scheduled" scope="col"></th>
                                            <th class="expander" scope="col"></th>
                                            <th class="name" scope="col"></th>
                                            <th class="description" scope="col"></th>
                                            <th class="modifiedDate" scope="col"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="resultGroup">
                                        <tr id="allResultsHeader" style="display:none;" class="content">
                                            <th class="typeHeader" colspan="6"><h4 id="resourceName" class="textAccent"></h4></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>


 <!--COMMENTED BY AARON: THIS IS THE BEGINNING OF THE PANEL THAT HAS THE LIST OF REPORTS--> 

                                <div id="resultContent" class="content setMyWidth setHeight" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                                    <div id="resourceList" class="wrapper tabularList setHidden">
                                        <table id="resultsTable" class="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr class="headers">
                                                <th class="bulkSelector" scope="col"></th>
                                                <th class="scheduled" scope="col"></th>
                                                <th class="expander" scope="col"></th>
                                                <th class="name" scope="col"></th>
                                                <th class="description" scope="col"></th>
                                                <th class="modifiedDate" scope="col"></th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody class="resultGroup">
                                            <tr colspan="5"></tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="allList" class="wrapper tabularList setHidden">

                                        <table id="allResultsTable" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody class="resultGroup">
                                            <!--COMMENTED BY AARON. To remove an extra row
            <tr colspan="5"></tr>
           -->
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

 <!--COMMENTED BY AARON: END OF THE PANEL THAT HAS THE LIST OF REPORTS-->

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="ajaxbuffer" style="display: none;"></div>
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="../repository/dragAndDrop.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="folder.jsp" %>

<div id="errorMsgBox" class="dialogFrame searchModalDialog" style="display: none; position: absolute;">

    <div class="dialogHeader" onMouseDown="dialogOnMouseDown(event);">
        <div id="errorMsgBoxTitle" class="dialogHeaderTitle"><spring:message code="SEARCH_CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE_BOX_TITLE"/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialogContent deleteDialogContent" onKeyPress="cancelEventBubbling(event);">
        <div id="errorMsgBoxMessage" class="dialogMessages wrap"></div>

        <div class="dialogButtons">
            <input id="errorMsgBoxOk" value="OK" type="button" class="dialogButton">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="confirmBox" class="dialogFrame searchModalDialog" style="display: none; position: absolute;">

    <div class="dialogHeader" onMouseDown="dialogOnMouseDown(event);">
        <div id="confirmBoxTitle" class="dialogHeaderTitle"><spring:message code="SEARCH_CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE_BOX_TITLE"/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="dialogContent deleteDialogContent" onKeyPress="cancelEventBubbling(event);">
        <div id="confirmBoxMesage" class="dialogMessages"></div>

        <div class="dialogButtons">
            <input id="confirmBoxOk" value="Yes" type="button" class="dialogButton">
            <input id="confirmBoxCancel" value="No" type="button" class="dialogButton">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<form id="redirectForm" action="flow.html" method="post" onSubmit="return false;" style="display:none;">
    <input id="_flowExecutionKey" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" type="hidden" />
    <input id="_eventId" name="_eventId" value="redirect" type="hidden" />
    <input id="flowParams" name="flowParams" value="" type="hidden" />
</form>

<!-- Page Specific Scripts -->
<script id="messagesScript" type="text/javascript">
    <c:forEach var="type" items="${searchConfiguration.labelsForTypes}"
    >messages["properties.type.${type}"] = '<spring:message code="resource.${type}.label" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="type" items="${searchConfiguration.supportedTypes}"
    >messages["${type}"] = '<spring:message code="SEARCH_${type}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="mode" items="${searchConfiguration.modes}"
    >messages["mode.<c:out value="${mode}"/>"] = '<spring:message code="SEARCH_MODE_${mode}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="type" items="${searchConfiguration.typeFilter.types}"
    >messages["${type.labelId}"] = '<spring:message code="${type.labelId}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="customFilter" items="${searchConfiguration.customFilters}">
        <c:forEach var="option" items="${customFilter.options}">
        messages["${option.labelId}"] = '<spring:message code="${option.labelId}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="sorter" items="${searchConfiguration.sorters}"
    >messages["sort.by.${sorter.id}"] = '<spring:message code="${sorter.labelId}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
    </c:forEach>

    messages["root.filter"] = '<spring:message code="SEARCH_ROOT_FILTER" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';

    messages["noResults"] = '<spring:message code="SEARCH_NO_RESULTS" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    // Init root object modifier variables.
    var organizationId = "${organizationId}";
    var publicFolderUri = "${publicFolderUri}";

    Search.Folder.publicUri = "${publicFolderUri}";

    JSAJAX.flowExecutionKey = '${flowExecutionKey}';
    Search.conf = ${searchConfiguration.json};

    <authz:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">
    Search.User.isAdministrator = true;
    </authz:authorize>

    <c:if test="${defaultTypeFilter != null}">
    Search.conf.typeFilter.defaultType = '${defaultTypeFilter}';
    </c:if>
    var search = {};

    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        CursorManager.initialize();
        KeyManager.initialize();
        MenuManager.initialize();

        search = new Search(${searchFilters});
        search.activate();

        new SearchDnD(search);
        new LayoutDnD();

        disableSelectionWithoutCursorStyle($('foldersTree'));
        disableSelectionWithoutCursorStyle($('vSizer'));
        disableSelectionWithoutCursorStyle($('searchMenuTemplate'));
        disableSelectionWithoutCursorStyle($('addMenuTemplate'));
        disableSelectionWithoutCursorStyle($('primaryPod'));
    });

    // Secondary search box initialization
    var jsSearchBoxSecondary = new JSSearchBox("js-search-secondary-control", "<spring:message code='SEARCH_BOX_DEFAULT_TEXT'/>",
            "<c:if test="${searchText != null}"><%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(request.getSession().getAttribute("searchText").toString())%></c:if>",
    {inputId: "secondarySearchText", clearBtnId: "secondaryClearBtn", searchBtnId: "secondarySearchBtn"});
    jsSearchBoxSecondary.onSearch = function(searchString) {
        search.showTypedList();
        search.notifyFilterSelected(Filter.Types.searchTermFilter, "'" + searchString + "'");
        search.loadData(searchString);
    };
    jsSearchBoxSecondary.onClear = function() {
        search.showTypedList();
        search.notifyFilterSelected(Filter.Types.searchTermFilter, "<spring:message code='SEARCH_ROOT_FILTER'/>");
        search.loadData("");
    };
    jsSearchBoxSecondary.activate();


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 // var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 // $j(function($) {
   // $j('#handler2').click(function(e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  // document.getElementById('handler2').click();
  // alert('hello');
   // });
 // });


 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById('handler2').click();
 });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is this block of code located? In `head` or before/after handler2?

Comment: It's at the bottom of the page, I can't get it to load if I put it in the head, although I don't know why, I usually put the js in the head?

Comment: Try using

    "jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});"

instead.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready giving me the same null error in firefox.

Comment: Is jquery loaded? I am sorry but I couldn't find it. AFAIK, you don't need noConflict if you use syntax that I suggest. Then you can use jQuery style $('#element-id') instead of document.getElementById('element-id').

Comment: There's no `id="handler2"` element present in that source. How about you compare the rendered HTML from both browsers?

Comment: sorry, jquery is the e.js file.  I'll post the output HTML...the HTML is being jenerated on the server and I don't have access to get at it until after it's been loaded in the DOM.

Comment: i've updated with another answer for the HTML output as best as I could get.

Comment: Ok, try to move e.js to above of your <script.... probably could fix the problem.

Comment: i'm confused...e.js is already above the script, unless I'm looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: All, thanks for your help. unfortunately I couldn't find an option that worked in both firefox and internet explorer. I think there is some kind of a conflict with firefox/mozilla running a jquery command when within a .jsp page using tomcat...I don't get the problem when using apache. So, I'm scrapping this idea and trying something else. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: Use `jQuery.ready(...)` (note no 'document'). Then you might as well keep using jQuery to find the element and operate on it O.o

Comment: **THERE IS NO "handler2" IN THAT HTML. FAIL.**

Comment: Did you try my idea of catching the image onload? Should be cross browser as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#handler2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but i can't get it to work.

Comment: weird.. it works here.. could you update your snippet to full source html instead of <script> portion only?

Comment: Ok, I posted the source code in another answer, because it had a lot of text.  I'm using a 3rd party java program and the problem is on one of the .jsp pages.

Answer (score 0):

I see "handler2" is an image, so I guess that jQuery document ready event is happening before all images finished loading.
Adding this to the image tag itself should work though:

```
onload="this.click();"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery to launch the function, but not to make the click happens. This seems wrong, since you might have to deal with browsers not supporting getElementById. Your code could read like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('#handler2').click();
    });
</script>
```

This makes jQuery perform the click. My experience is that this does not always work as expected. Best results are when you have the click event attached using jQuery.

What would be even smarter, is to bypass the click and perform the JavaScript that the click is supposed to execute. I'm assuming the click on #handler2 is some kind of JavaScript function, let's call it handler2_click().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        handler2_click(); // add params if necessary
    });
</script>
```

Comment: A browser not supporting getElementById? That runs jQuery? Serious?

Comment: Read "not supporting" as "having quirks". Like http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/ -- but for this small example you could be safe. I still dont see the point of using jQuery but not using jQuery's selectors though.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
(function($) {
    document.getElementById('handler2').click();
})(jQuery);
```